# C++ program to make linux Ubuntu clone windows partition?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, clone, kiosk

I want to write code in Dev C++ so that when i execute in Ubuntu 8 , it clones my windows 7 from D: partition to its child partitions E:,F: ... 
i have made my partitions of equal sizes and i have tested by manualy using ntfsclone ,so their will be no problem in cloning.

this is part of kiosk system and i hope you understand what i am upto

Some reference or help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you'd write your own when there are several freely available, from `dd` to g4u.

Comment: the purpose to make c++ or script code for doing this it consumes less time and automates the process easily by just executing one file.

Comment: It's I/O bound so "consuming less time" is bogus. *nix is perfectly capable of automation, so "automates the process" is also bogus.

Answer (score 0):

A script around dd or g4u can do what you want, and will likely be more efficient than anything you write yourself, as these are highly optimized tools. (With dd, at least, you'll probably want to do some testing around optimal block size for copies in your environment.)

Answer (score 0):

[dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) is going to save you a lot of time and headaches if you learn to use it.  To me, it seems like you're trying to re-invent the wheel here. dd is the perfect solution for this.